# How to apply order on hibernate projection result

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I used following hibernate criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
       projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("studentId"));
       projectionList.add(Projections.count("studentId"));
        criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
      return criteria.list();
```

This returns a list of objects and the objects have two fields, studentId and count(studentId). I want to sort this list by count(studentId) descending. How do I do this hibernate?

currently I am getting

```
{[1, 5], [2, 7], [3,4]}
```

I want to get it this

```
{[2, 7], [1, 5], [3,4]}
```

**solution:** 
this sloves the issue :)

```
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
            ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
           projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("studentId"));
           projectionList.add( Projections.alias(Projections.count("studentId"),"count"));
            criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
           criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(("count")));
            return criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no answer accepted - i formatted and simplified your own solution a bit:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("studentId"));
projectionList.add(Projections.count("studentId"), "count");
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(("count")));
return criteria.list();
```