# Using order by with aggregate functions in Hibernate Criteria API without projection

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql, hibernate-criteria

How can i convert the following SQL query to Hibernate Criteria API and HQL.

```
SELECT product.* FROM product JOIN product_likes ON product_likes.product = product.id 
    GROUP BY product.id 
    ORDER BY COUNT(product_likes.id) DESC
```

In the list I only want Product class entities.

Product and ProductLikes have One to Many relationship.

Class Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private ProductLikes productLikes;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ProductLikes getProductLikes() {
        return productLikes;
    }

    public void setProductLikes(ProductLikes productLikes) {
        this.productLikes = productLikes;
    }

}
```

Class ProductLikes

```
@Entity
public class ProductLikes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your class mappings

Comment: @SergeiBednar Product and ProductLikes have One to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question for discussing retrieval of **entities**, you can't avoid using projection, but I think it gets what you want. Specifically look at Jerome's answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29838324/6827719

And here's a very simple question where the user asks how to order by a projection:

[How to apply order on hibernate projection result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734405/how-to-apply-order-on-hibernate-projection-result)